# Firefox Addon SDK : prompt with multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox Add-On for a client.

When an user is uninstalling the Add-On, I need to show the user a prompt, which contains three checkboxes. These checkboxes will serve as an option to the user for restoring his/her previous browser settings.

I've successfully created a prompt on [uninstall/disable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload), using the [`confirmCheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPromptService#confirmCheck()) method of the [nsIPromptService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPromptService) interface :

```
let value = {value: true};

let confirm = promptService.confirmCheck(
    null,
    "Uninstall My Extension",
    "You are uninstalling My Extension. You can chose these options to restore your settings to previous state.",
    "Remove My Extension as the default search engine, homepage, new tab landing page, and restore to my previous settings",
    value
);
```

The only problem is, it only contains a single checkbox, and I need 3 different ones, for "Seach Engine", "Homepage", and "New Tab Url" each.

I'm using chrome code through the Add-On SDK, and am not familiar with XUL.

How should I go about this? Do I really need to learn XUL for creating a simple prompt?

Comment: You can do three different buttons: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIPromptService?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=nsIPromptService#confirmEx_example. But for three checks boxes you have to make your own prompt either with XUL or HTML.

Comment: @Noitidart Different buttons isn't an option for me. Is there any tutorial for HTML prompts? I didn't know that that HTML can be used in prompts instead of XUL.

Comment: You absolutely can. Open a new window with `Services.ww.openWindow` make it modal and load an HTML page. OR overlay your current window with a xul element such as stack, deck, or other overlapping, append an iframe and load an html page there. Install this addon from this repo: https://github.com/Noitidart/adhelp/tree/patch-1 use [GitHub Extension Installer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-extension-installer/) after install, restart browser, press alt for menu bar, see the "AdHelp" menu item, chose the "Picture"i tem from it, it overlays current tab.

Comment: That simple demo addon makes the prompt per tab, you can make it overlap your the browser window making it act modal if you want to.

Comment: @Noitidart When I open a new window using `nsIWindowWatcher` (`openWindow`), and load an html page into it, it successfully opens. However, by the time it opens, the addon is already disabled. Is there any way to block the execution while the prompt is open? Also, how can I know which checkboxes have been ticked, after the user closes the prompt?

Comment: @Noitidart Alright, I resolved the execution issue by adding `dialog` to features. Now the only problem which remains, how do I close the window on `OK` button, and how to pass checkbox data to the main script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, answering my own question, as I figured it out. The easiest way I found (comparatively) was to use XUL :

This is my prompt.xul :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/global.css" type="text/css"?>
<dialog id="myDialog"
        title="My Extension"
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
        onload="init();"
        buttons="accept"
        buttonlabelaccept="OK"
        ondialogaccept="return doContinue();">

    <script type="application/x-javascript">
        function init() {

        }

        function doContinue() {
            window.arguments[0].CHECK_1 = document.querySelector('#check_1').checked;
            window.arguments[0].CHECK_2 = document.querySelector('#check_2').checked;
            window.arguments[0].CHECK_3 = document.querySelector('#check_3').checked;
            return true;
        }
    </script>

    <html:div style="width: 410px;">
        <html:div>
            <html:p>You have selected to uninstall My Extension</html:p>
        </html:div>
        <html:blockquote id="checkboxes_container">
            <html:div id="remove_search_container">
                <html:input type="checkbox" id="check_1" value="true" checked="true"/>
                <html:label for="check_1">Label 1</html:label>
            </html:div>
            <html:div id="remove_homepage_container">
                <html:input type="checkbox" id="check_2" value="true" checked="true"/>
                <html:label for="check_2">Label 2</html:label>
            </html:div>
            <html:div id="remove_newtab_container">
                <html:input type="checkbox" id="check_3" value="true" checked="true"/>
                <html:label for="check_3">Label 3</html:label>
            </html:div>
        </html:blockquote>
    </html:div>
</dialog>
```

After adding the chrome package to `chrome.manifest`, this file should be accessible by :

```
chrome://YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/content/PATH_TO_dialog.xul
```

I'm using chrome code to load the prompt, in `main.js` :

```
let Window = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1"]
            .getService(Ci.nsIWindowWatcher);

let arg = {

    CHECK_1: false,

    CHECK_2: false,

    CHECK_3: false

};

let window = Window.activeWindow.openDialog("chrome://YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/content/PATH_TO_dialog.xul", "myWindow", "chrome,modal,centerscreen", arg);
```

After the user has closed the prompt, the `arg` object will contain the checkbox values of the prompt. For example, if an user ticks all the checkboxes, the `arg` object will be :

```
{

    CHECK_1 : true,

    CHECK_2 : true,

    CHECK_3 : true

}
```

And that did it for me. Have a nice day!